# Notepad++ menu font is white. How o change it

Tags: notepad++

I have messed up notepad++ such that the menu font appears in white.
Not sure how to change it. Any tips?

[image]

Comment: You could try finding a solution here: https://superuser.com/questions/540286/notepad-how-to-reset-all-the-setting-to-default-ones

Comment: Could reinstall, if that could be an option.

Answer (score 0):

If you use vanilla Notepad++, then reinstall it.

My personal experience is, that reinstalling is by 95% the fastest option, if the problem is something like this.

It will take 5 minutes.